# How to return specific rows from InfluxDB measurement when the column contains a string value

Tags: influxdb

Basically, I am looking for an equivalent of "LIKE" keyword as in SQL. Is there any way we can get those rows where column contains specific string?

For e.g. from below table/measurement, can we get the row where column "data" contains "find"? i.e. 2nd row.

**Col1**          **Col2**              **Col3**

first str     second str      third str

first str     second str      third str, find me

first str     second str      third str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `=~`  operator to compare to a regex. Eg:

```
select * from yourmeasure where col3 =~ /find/i
```

The `i` makes it case insensitive. Remove this if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that's what I needed. For some reason 'i' isn't working (no data shows if I mention 'i' to make it case insensetive) but that's not the issue at least for now.